# Passport.js - passing {user: req.user} to template implicitly?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

Using Passport.js and Express for multiple projects now, I have noticed myself doing this over and over again, namely specifying `{ user: req.user }` explicitly for my Express routes. Ocassionally I forget to pass it, and suddenly it's like user is not even logged in anymore.

How can I pass a `user` *variable* in my routes without having to explicitly write it for each route like this?

```
app.get = function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('home', {
        title: 'Home',
        user: req.user
    });
};
```

I think [everyauth](http://everyauth.com/#express-helpers) has such Express helper, but does Passport.js?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You could use a simple middleware for that:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.user = req.user;
  next();
});
```

This will make a `user` variable available in all templates, provided that `req.user` is populated. Make sure that you declare that middleware *after* you declare the `passport.session` middleware, but before any routes.