# Getting data in view after auth

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I'm trying to show the users name on the page after the authentication. whenever I do so, the page just crashes because I show my route in both my server.js file and my login route file.

**EDIT;** eg. When you log in you arrive on the Topic page. I would like to pass data from the login to that page, but it doesn't seem as easy as I first thought it was because of passportjs.

At the moment the route is done via the server.js file and the Topic route file, but I would like to change it so it uses the login route file so I can pass login data to the view.

An example would be the page saying 'Hi, Joren!' in the header.

Div in my view

```
<div>
    <h1>Profile Name</h1>
        <% if (user.local.email && user.local.password){ %>
            <%= user.local.name %>
        <% } %>
        <% if (user.facebook.name && user.facebook.email ){ %>
            <p><%= user.facebook.name %></p>
         <% } %>
</div>
```

The problem is that it can't find local if I just use the route.

Route - passportjs login.js

```
app.get('/topic', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    res.render('create_topic.ejs', {
        user : req.user
    });
});

function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();
    res.redirect('/');
}
```

server.js

```
var topics = require('./routes/topic');
app.use('/topic', topics);
```

Topic route

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Topic = require('../models/topicModel.js');

    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
        res.render('create_topic.ejs', { title: 'Topics', user: req.user });
    });

    router.get('/id/:id', function(req, res, next) {
        console.log("Sup boi");
        var id = req.params.id;

        Topic.findOne({topicID: id}, function(err, doc){
            res.render('questions.ejs', {docs: doc});
        });
    });

module.exports = router;
```

When I use the login route file as a route for the topic page I get this error when I click a specific topic because it can't link to the Topic page with the specific ID.

> Cannot Get Topic/id/*idnumber*

When I try to get the local auth data it throws this error (see view at top).

> Local is not defined

**edit** Trid to make the question more clear.

Comment: I would love to help but your question is really unclear to me.

Comment: @ThomasBormans Made an edit to make the question more clear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passport.js - passing {user: req.user} to template implicitly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20912283/passport-js-passing-user-req-user-to-template-implicitly). It sounds to me like you are asking how to get the logged in user to every template.  If so, the above should help you.

Comment: if I do it like this though it doesn't route throught the server.js and model. I just get the can't GET /id/*id* error. i'm trying to add this to the login.js route for passportjs;     app.get('/topic', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
        res.render('create_topic.ejs', {
            user : req.user
        });
    });